# Rules link get url parameters

Tags: views, rules

I've got a rule link in a view
Rules link generates me this link per user displayed by the view

http://localhost/drupaltest/addequpier/18/14/6OwljLX8KLBfNPrW37bzulzuue25VJmkzWtGiPmR-mc

18 is the user id
14 the node id (i've added this parameter with rewrite url)

How can get those parameters from the url with rules ? Do i have to rewrite the url ?

I'm using Drupal 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resolved my problem finaly, I think there was a conflict with a Disabled module (Rules Forms).
I can set the displayed variables under "parameters" in my rule config.